# How to count people who are below a position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, automation, data-science

I'm looking to count how many people are below a given user of the data frame.

| Employee | Manager |
| --- | --- |
| A | - |
| B | A |
| C | A |
| D | A |
| E | A |
| F | B |
| G | B |
| H | C |
| I | C |

I would like to get in the output:
I, H, G, F, E and D have no employees below
C has two employees (H and I) below it
B has two employees (F and G)
A has eight employees below him (B, C, D and E plus the employees of B and C)

Would anyone have any suggestions?
In my DF I have more hierarchy layers and a very large amount of data.

I thought about storing it in a dictionary and doing a loop to update it, but I believe that this solution is not efficient at all. I would like to know if there is any more efficient technique to solve this type of problem.

Comment: You can use `networkx` to solve this graph problem.

Comment: @Corralien I'm studying this library and checking the examples but I still haven't been able to apply it to my case. Do you have any examples of NetworkX application in this sense?

Comment: Did the below answer solve your problem or not?

Comment: The answer below helped me a lot forward in the solution. Initially I was perplexed. But my result still has some problems that I'm trying to adjust. For this, I am reading the other comments and suggestions and exploring these paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a directed graph with `networkx`. This is a super fun python package.

```
import networkx as nx, pandas as pd

#set up data
employee = ['A', 'B', 'C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
manager = ['', 'A', 'A','A','A','B','B','C','C']
relations = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(employee,manager)), columns = ['Employee', 'Manager'])

# If there is no manager, make it the employee
relations.Manager = np.where(relations.Manager == '', relations.Employee, relations.Manager)
# or might need depending on data format:
relations.Manager = np.where(relations.Manager.isna(), relations.Employee, relations.Manager)

# Create tuples for 'edges'
relations['edge'] = list(zip(relations.Manager, relations.Employee))

# Create graph
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(list(relations.Employee))
G.add_edges_from(list(set(relations.edge)))

#Find all the descendants of nodes/employees
relations['employees_below'] = relations.apply(lambda row: nx.descendants(G,row.Employee), axis = 1)
```

returns:

```
  Employee Manager    edge           employees_below
0        A       A  (A, A)  {C, G, I, D, H, F, E, B}
1        B       A  (A, B)                    {F, G}
2        C       A  (A, C)                    {H, I}
3        D       A  (A, D)                        {}
4        E       A  (A, E)                        {}
5        F       B  (B, F)                        {}
6        G       B  (B, G)                        {}
7        H       C  (C, H)                        {}
8        I       C  (C, I)                        {}
```

The way it works: graphs are nodes and edges. In this case, your nodes are employees and your edges are a relationship between a manager and an employee. Do a quick google for 'networkx directed graph' images and you'll get the idea of what this looks like in an image representation.

- Make sure your data is cleaned up where everyone has a manager (make it themselves if there is none, for example)
- First, create your edges in the form of a tuple of `(manager, employee)` and save it somewhere (I chose to make it a column in the `df` called `edges`).
- Next, make a directed graph in networkx. A directed graph is needed due to the hierarchical relationship. this means that relationships work down from manager to employee. So, in this case, each edge goes in a direction from manager to employee.
- Add every employee to your graph as a 'node'.
- Add every employee-manager relationship to your graph as an edge, using the pre-defined tuples of `(manager, employee)` discussed previously.
- Lastly, you can get the output of an employee's subordinates by finding all this node's descendants. Descendants are all nodes (ie, employees) that can be reached from a node (ie, employee). I chose to assign this to a column and apply the `descendants` function to the employee in each row with `apply`.

Comment: First, I would like to thank you for your attention and for submitting a suggestion. I didn't know about this NetworkX library, I'll read more about it and try to apply your idea to my problem.
Again, thank you very much!

Comment: I've added additional explanation below, and there is some in the comments of the sample code too. Happy to discuss anything further if there is confusion

Comment: Hello!
Today I went back to the hierarchy problem I was solving and tried to implement your suggestion. However, the returned dataframe ended up duplicating elements. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm researching other ways, but I believe that the presented library will solve my problem. I'm reading the documentation to try to implement.

Today I researched other paths as well and what I'm looking for is similar to a family tree but applied to the business. Anyway, I'm happy with the suggestions and excited to solve this problem.

Comment: interesting, do you mean duplicates of employees, managers, or duplicate subordinates after using `nx.descendants`? I wonder if it is related to your dataframe at all. Are there any duplicate `employee` rows where an employee is listed as having more than one manager through multiple entries? Or the same row shows up (mess around with `duplicates` and `drop_duplicates` if so). Or is it cyclic in some way by chance, which can lead to issues (maybe it shouldn't have the `(A,A)` type edge added due to risk of cyclical graph?) Just some thoughts on how to troubleshoot

Comment: I'm sorry. I reviewed the code (actually rewrote it) and now it works. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

As originally mentioned by @34jbonz networkx is the best tool for the task. There is however no need to preprocess the data as networkx provides a pandas interface

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(temp, source='manager',target='employee',create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

also the use of `apply` and `descendants` should be avoided as it results in some calculations being done multiple times. Here a depth first search is the most efficient solution

```
for node in nx.dfs_postorder_nodes(G,'-'):
    successors = list(G.successors(node))
    G.nodes[node]['size'] = sum([G.nodes[p]['size'] for p in successors]) + len(successors)
    G.nodes[node]['descendants'] = [s for sn in successors for s in G.nodes[sn]['descendants']]\
        + successors
```

finally information can be extracted in bulk from a networkx graph as a dict, which in turn can be transformed into a dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(G.nodes(data=True)),orient='index')
```

Comment: Hello @Arnau! I tried to implement your suggestion but I have some doubts.
I don't understand the 'temp' parameter you used. I would also like to know if this way I can access the number of people who are below the manager.

Comment: Hello Bruno, temp is just the name of the dataframe containing the employee and manager columns. The result contains the number of employees below a manager as well as a list of which employees they are.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Arnau!
I will try to implement in my solution again.

Comment: Good morning, @Arnau!
All good?
I went back on the problem today and tried to implement your suggestions and other questions came up (sorry).
in nx.dfs_postorder_nodes(G, '-') return key error for '-'.
I checked the documentation and it is an optional parameter source.
Therefore, I removed this parameter to verify that the code would now advance and I had another key error but now for the size in
G.nodes[node]['size'] = sum(G.nodes[p]['size'] for p in successors])
I don't understand where I'm failing